# juju Charmstore server install failed

Tags: juju

I want to install juju charm store in local machine. After I installed charm-store (https://github.com/juju/charmstore) I retrieve some charms from public repository using `charmload cmd/charmd/config.yaml`, so I can see 28 charms in mongodb. So After installing charm-store server it starts listening on port 8080. But I can't see any charm info. It means when I browse to `/charm-info` or `/charm-event` or `/charm/` it gives empty value. I can't find out where is the error. I have installed mongodb. It always gives empty brackets **{}**. So can anyone tell me how to check logs or what happened here.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions in the README.md (https://github.com/juju/charmstore) ?
To specify a config.yaml file to the `charmload` command, use `-config` before the path. Because you're seeing only 28 charms this implies the import was not performed correctly, as it says in the README you can expect ~1050 charms in the DB and it might take more than 2 hours. Then you need to use `charmd cmd/charmd/config.yaml` to start the server on port 8080 and you should be able to access the /charm-info and other URLs.

I hope this helps!.